# Create a digital signature hash via Gnosis/Safe Multisig Wallet

Tags: wallets, gnosis-safe, smart-contract-wallets, signature, multisignature

I have a multisig wallet setup at https://safe.global/. I need to prepare a TX which calls a contract, and one of the parameters of the function I am calling needs a digital signature of the (tightly encoded) passed-in function parameters. How do I construct this digital signature hash parameter? If I would have access to the private key, I could construct it myself (programmatically, e.g. via hot wallet), but since I don't have access to the multisig wallet's private key, naturally, how can I do the same in this case?

Comment: Does the contract support ERC-1271? https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271 If not then it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can execute this function , because multisig dont have a private key , its a Smart Contract Wallet . So , it cant be done . One thing you can try , you can pass the signature of your metamask wallet which is the owner of the multisig wallet.

I hope this helps